# Rails time_select set default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am using time_select in a rails view, it looks something like this:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :StartTime, "Start Time" %><br />
    <%= f.time_select :StartTime %>
</div>
```

I want to set the default time to 09:00 (AM), how would I do that?

Comment: Hint: if you post a block of code, indent it by 4 spaces. Backticks are for highlighting small inline portions of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about setting corresponding model property?

```
def new
  @session = Session.new
  @session.StartTime = Time.now.beginning_of_day + 9.hours
end
```

Note that in Ruby it's against widely accepted conventions to name methods in PascalCase. `StartTime` should become `start_time`.

(I took the liberty of naming the model `Session`, since you didn't specify any name).